# Need to install Xamarin Android Support Library v4

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Need to install Support library v4 but I cannot select 4.0 in the options to target the android app. it has options to target 2.3 and 4.1 none of these work. 
What should I do.

The reason I need it is in order to use "viewpager"

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;
```

thanks

Comment: ? Add it via the Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/

Comment: Youre targeting to API level10, but you did compile with newest framework?

Comment: how do I get the console to add in the commands?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Visual Studio or Xamarin Studio?